# MS-Access 2003 Deleted my Switchboard Form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I have made a rookie mistake and deleted my Form Switchboard.  I have all of my switchboard controls in teh Switchboard manager, but no form.  How can I get it back or create a new one based off of the existing controls?

Comment: Your rookie mistake wasn't deleting something, it was not having backups.

Comment: Agreed!  I had backed up prior to creating my switchboard.

Comment: From what I have been able to compile from my research is that recovery of a non backed up item is not possible.  I have gone in and recreated the form.

Comment: One of the few advantages of Access is that to back up your data, just copy and paste the file.  If you want to get fancy, move your backup copy to a cloud drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the *Switchboard Manager* to edit your `Switchboard` form, the form itself is not altered.  Instead your changes are saved to a table, `Switchboard Items`, which feeds the form.

Deleting the form doesn't necessarily delete the table.  As long as that table is still present, you can recover the form's previous state:

1. rename the `Switchboard Items` table to `xSwitchboard Items`
2. start the *Switchboard Manager*
3. click `Yes` when it asks for permission to create a new switchboard
4. make *any* edit to the new switchboard
5. close the *Switchboard Manager* and confirm the new Switchboard form is operable
6. close the form
7. delete the new `Switchboard Items` table
8. rename the `xSwitchboard Items` table to `Switchboard Items`

Then whenever you open the `Switchboard` form again, it will read everything it needs from the original version of `Switchboard Items`.

OTOH, if the original `Switchboard Items` table was also deleted when you deleted the form, you're out of luck and the only solution is to restore from backup.

BTW, my impression is that many experienced Access developers seem to dislike that Switchboard feature.  It's too limited and inflexible.